# PHP if in POST load only the first if

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code :

```
    if(isset($_POST['remove'])){

                      $con = mysqli_connect(".","","","");

                $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");

        header( "refresh:2;url=settings.php" );
        echo "<div class='notemarg'>Profile Picture has been removed. Refreshing page within 3 seconds...</div>";
}
```

It is working, but I want it to do something like this

```
    if(isset($_POST['remove'])){

                      $con = mysqli_connect("","","","");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
                                    if($row['picture'] == ""){
                                echo "<div class='notemarg'> No pictures to delete</div>";
        } else {
                $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");

        header( "refresh:2;url=settings.php" );
        echo "<div class='notemarg'>Profile Picture has been removed. Refreshing page within 3 seconds...</div>";
        }
        }
}
```

This means that the picture from database will be removed only if there IS any picture.. if not, then it will display that message "No pictures to delete" ... but it does not work.. it still shows that error message that there is no picture even though there is no blank row in database and so it does not delete the information in row either...
Where is problem?
BTW: first code works fine... and it works even if there is nothing in database so it kinda does not make sense that the "profile picture has been removed." is being displayed...

Comment: you are missing the mysqli_query for the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
  $con = mysqli_connect("","","","");
 if(isset($_POST['remove'])){

   $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT picutre FROM members where username = '". $_SESSION['username']. "'");          
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
   if( empty($row['picture'])){
      echo "<div class='notemarg'> No pictures to delete</div>";
   } 
   else {
     $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");

     header( "refresh:2;url=settings.php" );
     echo "<div class='notemarg'>Profile Picture has been removed. Refreshing page within 3 seconds...</div>";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need the `mysqli_query` statement:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("","","","");
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT IFNULL(picture,'') AS picture
                        FROM members 
                        WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
    if( empty($row['picture'])){
      echo "<div class='notemarg'> No pictures to delete</div>";
    } 
    else {
      $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");

      header( "refresh:2;url=settings.php" );
      echo "<div class='notemarg'>Profile Picture has been removed. Refreshing page within 3 seconds...</div>";
    }
 }
```